# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS - Dynamic Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have three tables :

- [Product] : ProductId,ProductName,...
- [A] : AID,ProductId...
- [B] : BID,ProductId...

I want to get data from table Product with condition :

select ProductId from Product where ProductId in(ProductId of Table [A] **Union** ProductId of Table [B]).

I create SP (dynamic sql) as :

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchProduct]
( 
@ProductId int = null, @ProductName nvarchar(50) = null,@ProductCat int = null
)
as
declare @SqlStr nvarchar(max)
declare @ParamList nvarchar(200)

if @ProductCat = 0
    // error here :Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS
    select @SqlStr='select p.* from dbo.Product p where ProductId in
                            (select ProductId from dbo.A where ProductId=@ProductId
                            union 
                            select ProductId from dbo.B where ProductId=@ProductId )'
```

Comment: you can modify the IN statement to be an EXISTS statement if you want, and produce the same result... e.g. `SELECT p.* FROM dbo.Product p WHERE ProductId = @ProductId AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.A WHERE ProductId = p.ProductId UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM dbo.B WHERE ProductId = p.ProductId)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to move the filtering conditions to split the conditions into two:

```
select p.*
from dbo.Product p
where ProductId in (select ProductId from dbo.A where ProductId = @ProductId) or
      ProductId in (select ProductId from dbo.B where ProductId = @ProductId );
```

`Union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates and can also impede the use of indexes.

Comment: Thank you , Gordon. But i still get error : Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Comment: @Mr.Ken . . . I don't see how this query could produce that error -- obviously, all the subqueries are only returning one column.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. In this case you don't need to use dynamic query

```
select p.* from dbo.Product p 
join (select ProductId from dbo.A where ProductId=@ProductId
    union 
    select ProductId from dbo.B where ProductId=@ProductId ) t
    on t.ProductId=p.ProductId
```

OR

```
    select p.* from dbo.Product p 
join (select ProductId from dbo.A 
    union 
    select ProductId from dbo.B ) t
    on t.ProductId=p.ProductId

    where t.ProductId=@ProductId
```